# Как создать пользователя с правами только на чтение (pure-ftpd)?

Tags: ftp

Используется pure-ftpd. Как создать виртуального пользователя, имеющего права только на чтение?

`chmod`, думаю, не подойдет, так как есть еще один пользователь, просматривающий и редактирующий данную директорию.

Comment: Установите [UserManager][1].  [1]: http://yandex.ua/yandsearch?text=UserManager+for+pureftpd&tld=ua&lr=143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот небольшой мануал: [настройка FTP сервера (используем PureFTPd)](http://pclinuxos.su/index.php/server/ftp-server/74-nastrojka-ftp-servera-ispolzuem-pureftpd).